# How can I get back the dynamically created objects of a class?

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt, pyside

I have *a list of strings* **my_list** with n amount of items in it.
This list gets entered strings one by during runtime.
Let's say there are 4 items for now.

Example: my_list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

I have *a custom object* called **my_object**, of which instances I need to create with a loop, **for each item in the list**.

My questions:
Normally, I create objects as: `**my_obj** = MyObj()` and I can use **my_obj** variable to get it and call its methods etc.

Since I need this creation to happen dynamically, with a list operation;

- How can I create object instances?
- How can I get an object instance and call its methods?

I know it's old, probably wrong and outdated but in VisualBasic for visual items this could have been performed like:

my_obj[dyanmic_variable] = ...

I don't want this to be complicated involving globals or anything.

How can I handle this problem?

***More Context:***

*I am developing an application using Qt (PySide - PyQt).
I have a custom made widget (my_class)
I need to populate a visual list (QGridLayout) with dynamically created instances of this object and then call their methods.*

Thank you.

***Code that shows I am creating objects and try to use them:***

```
class my_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'hi'
    def talk(w):
        print w

my_list = ['one', 'two']

### code that won't work starts from here 
for i in list:
    i = my_class()

my_list[1].talk()
```

Comment: Please show actual code that demonstrates what you're trying to do and what about it is not working.

Comment: Code of what exactly? I would love to do that but that's what I am asking. I have a random custom class that does not do anything yet. My question is to how to create dynamic instances and I don't know the code for it.

Comment: You create an object by calling a class, e.g. `MyClass()`. There's no requirement to assign it to a variable. Your "problem" sounds silly enough that I think we are missing context. Show code.

Comment: @Phil: Code that shows you creating the objects and trying to use them.

Comment: All classes and objects are created dynamically (i.e., at run time). There is no "non-dynamic" way of doing it. And to retrieve it at a later time, just make sure it's in scope somehow (via a variable, property, collection, etc) and go get it.

Comment: @FrancisAvila, thank you. I shall say though in two different parts of the question, I tried to elaborate the matter using plain English. I know about run-time and dynamic and static when it comes to computer science. However in my question, in plain English, "dynamic" is referring to reading a STRING from a LIST and using that STRING as an object instance name. So do you know how to do that?

Comment: Objects don't have names. You probably want a dict with strings as the keys (the "names") and your objects as the values, but it's hard to tell. Are you sure you have read the Python tutorial? I haven't done much VB programming but I don't remember a name/value paradigm fundamentally different from Python. Even in VB I would use an array, Collection, or Dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be confused about the meaning of "variables" and "names" in Python.

Objects do not have names. Saying `foo = 1` doesn't do anything to the `1` object except increase its reference count.

Variables are a mapping of a string to an object within a namespace. Namespaces are implemented with dicts. You can access the local namespace with the `locals()` function.

Example:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> locals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
>>> a = 1
>>> locals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, 'a': 1, '__package__': None}
>>>
```

Notice that 'a':1 appears in the `locals()` dictionary.

Your question is still unclear because you don't show any code with the task you want to accomplish and where you are stuck. Probably the best way to do what I think you are trying to do (although not necessary how to do what you want to do) is to use a dict:

```
>>> class MyClass(object): pass
... 
>>> myobjects = {}
>>> myobjects['key-name'] = MyClass()
>>> myvar = myobjects['key-name']  # some time later...
>>> myvar # what is myvar?
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x10f7c1c50>
>>> myobjects['key-name'] # myobjects['key-name'] is the same object
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x10f7c1c50>
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you just saying you want to create a list of objects without names?  Just do something like this:

```
myObjs = [MyObj() for i in range(5)]
```

Then you can access each object with `myObjs[0]`, `myObjs[1]`, etc.

Also, read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to familiarize yourself with the basics of creating class instances, lists, etc. in Python.

Edit: What you describe in the comment (creating a variable with a given name) is not a good idea.  It doesn't make sense to create a dynamic variable name because you can't use it in code without knowing what the variable name is.  It's better to use a list or dict.  For a dict, you could do something like:

```
myObjs = {}
theName = getNameSomehowFromUser()
myObjs[theName] = MyObj()
```

And then do that as often as you want, adding new objects to the dict called `myObjs`.

Comment: @BrenBam, thank you for your kind answer. I understand your suggested way. So basically you are suggesting that I should create a new list of objects and use list index to retrieve them? I understand this, thank you, I shall apply it. However I must tell you that I did read quite a bit about Python and docs and completed course(s) as well. I just thought there would be a built-in way to dynamically name instances and reach them later like in ancient VisualBasic.

Comment: @Phil Do you mean a dict? Is that what you want?

Comment: @Marcin, imagine an application which receives a string at the runtime from the user. I want Python to create instance of a class and make that received string the variable name and then retrieve that created instance using that string at a later time.

Comment: @Phil: That is not a good idea.  Instead use a list or dict to hold your objects.  See my edited answer.

Comment: @Phil Do what BrenBarn suggests. It would also be nice if you accepted an answer if you feel any solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved the issue:

I decided to use a class property called 'instances' to which I append all newly created instances. This can be a dict or a list. A string or an index int then can be used to retrieve them.

Awesome.